# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure with newly created app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

we are created new development environment so I cloned a current working app service into a new one and changed the configurations and deployed same code but the new app service is returning `HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure`
after trying the console for more details that's what I get, I don't think its related to runtime identifier because same code runs on different exact app services [image]

Comment: It seems you are lacking of the required library named `hostpolicy.dll` . How do you clone your app?

Comment: through clone app feature in azure

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396782/error-loading-hostpolicy-dll-while-deploying-net-core-console-app-to-azure-webj

Comment: And you could trouble shooting like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053677/azure-unhandled-exception-system-io-filenotfoundexception/63065704#63065704

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dreaded 500.3x ACNM error can mean different things, so I'm going to assist you in pinpointing those things.

My recommendation:
Go to Azure Portal > Your App Service > development tools

Open console.

Screen should look like this:
[Console Screen Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tesuG.png)

Type in (YourWebAppName).exe

What this will do, is show error messages that are relevant to your startup issue.

Also, some information regarding errors can be seen here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1#app-startup-errors

Comment: I did that already and above in the screenshot is what I got timeout