# An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll with Azure Function With Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

I've trouble with running my isolated .NET 5 Azure Function on my local computer and Visual Studio 2022. I've next message:

[image: Visual Studio error message]

[image: Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console]

> Failed to load the dll from [C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.30.1\cli_x64\hostpolicy.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1
>
> An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll from [C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.30.1\cli_x64]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 15628) exited with code -2147450750.
>
> Press any key to close this window . . .

Here is the code of the project:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Some code here -->
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Some code here -->
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I've tried these things:

1. Adding `<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifiers>` to the `PropertyGroup` tag of the project file _(like on this question [Error loading hostpolicy.dll while deploying .NET Core console app to Azure WebJobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396782/error-loading-hostpolicy-dll-while-deploying-net-core-console-app-to-azure-webj)) → Didn't work
2. Setting the path environment variable `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` above `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\` *(like on this article [.NET 6 Azure Functions Isolated: An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll](https://kontext.tech/column/cloud-azure/848/net-6-azure-functions-isolated-an-error-occurred-while-loading-required-library-hostpolicydll))* → Didn't work
3. Droped and recreated the project → Didn't work
4. Switching to Visual Studio 2019 → Working

Why doesn't it work with Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: I'm troubleshooting the same problem with my project right now.  Curious, have you installed Visual Studio 2022?  I have and I'm wondering if that is causing the problem.

Comment: @ChadGreen: Yes I'm using Visual Studio 2022 preview

Comment: @ChadGreen: I've updated my question. It's only 2022. Using 2019 it's working.

Comment: That's ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT.  You're running the 32-bit version of dotnet.exe (note how it got loaded from c:\program files (x86)) but try to load a 64-bit DLL.  Not good, run c:\program files\dotnet\dotnet.exe instead.

Answer (score 2):

Hans Passant spotted the right answer: the 32-bit version of dotnet.exe is trying to load a 64-bit DLL. Look at your path and remove the x86 path to 32-bit dotnet.exe. Restart Visual Studio 2022 and it should work properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33990219)